# nHibernate 3.0 queries

Tags: nhibernate

Working through the summer of nHibernate tutorials have gotten to the section on queries. Seems there have been changes since that series was made. So I went to the online docs for nHB 3.0 but code such as:

```
IList cats = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cat))
            .Add(Expression.Like("Name", "Fritz%"))
            .Add(Expression.Between("Weight", minWeight, maxWeight))
            .List();
```

Generates the error "The name 'Expression' does not exist in the current context"

Code like:

```
return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(DataTransfer.Customer))
            .Add(new NHibernate.Criterion.LikeExpression("Firstname", firstname))
            .Add(new NHibernate.Criterion.LikeExpression("Lastname", lastname))
            .List<Customer>();
```

Works but it seems that it is missing a number of query methods like GtExpression.
Are the online docs up to date, and if so, why can't I use Expression...
If the online docs aren't up to date then where do I get a description of the Criterion interface?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `using NHibernate.Criterion;`.

Anyway, the `Expression` class is deprecated. Use `Restrictions` instead.

Comment: Yes thanks, I was missing the using statement, and the emphasis on "Restrictions" is why the documentation had me confused.

Answer (score 0):

Weird thing. I still use Expression.* static methods and these are still work. Are you sure you use the latest version of NH3.0? I use Alpha 2 version.

If you need to make it work urgently, let's try the QueryOver<> feature:

```
return session.QueryOver<DataTransfer.Customer>()
  .WhereRestrictionOn(u => u.Name).IsLike("Fritz%")
  .AndRestrictionOn(u => u.Weight).IsBetween(minWeight).And(maxWeight)
  .List();
```

It works well for simple queries